# IntelliTrace disappearing with certain projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a rather big project consisting of multiple projects in a solution. One of them is a now rather big Console application. When I debug this console application, the IntelliTrace Window does not appear in Visual Studio. But whenever I try debugging any other (WinForms) project, IntelliTrace appears as it should. When debugging, the IntelliTrace options in the Debug>Windows menu also disappear, leaving me with the Debug>IntelliTrace menu, which has all but one option greyed out (open IntelliTrace settings).

I hope somebody can help me with this one, I've never had any problem of this sort before.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'll check is whether "native code debugging" is enabled. IntelliTrace won't be enabled with native code debugging. You can open the properties for your project and look at "Debug" tab. There's should be something similar to this screenshot.

[image]